# Check if a Row exists in a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, row

I am having trouble fixing my code so that I stop getting

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
```

Here is my current code:

```
    public static boolean isRow(int row, double[][] array)
    {
    boolean flag = false;

    if ( array != null && array.length >= 0 )
    {
        if ( array[row] != null )
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
    }
```

I know that I will probably have to have a for loop somewhere so that it can check to see that

`!(row > array.length);`

But I am just not sure how to write that in. I am using a JUNIT test that is trying to pass "6" in as the row variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well isnt array a double array? and your treating it like a single? if ( array[row] != null )
        {
            flag = true;

Comment: so maybe try array[row][0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that `row` is in range for the array:

```
public static boolean isRow(int row, double[][] array)
{
    boolean flag = false;

    if (array != null && row >= 0 && row < array.length)
    {
        if ( array[row] != null )
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

or, more concisely (taking advantage of the [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) nature of the `&&` operator):

```
public static boolean isRow(int row, double[][] array)
{
    return array != null && row >= 0 && row < array.length && array[row] != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this helped completely!

Comment: @user3254134 - Glad to help. Note that the test `array.length >= 0` is completely unnecessary: so long as `array != null`, then `array.length` is always a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

Check if array[row] exists before requesting it in you if test.

```
public static boolean isRow(int row, double[][] array)
{
boolean flag = false;

if ( array != null && array.length >= 0 && array.length > row)
{
    if ( array[row] != null )
    {
        flag = true;
    }
}
return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, all you need to check is that the row with the given index is available in the array. For which, as you wrote:

```
!(row >= array.length);
```

is enough. If the array has 6 elements, array.length will return 6. If the row index being passed is anything less than 6, it is a valid row (obv row has to be >= 0).

Edit: please notice the change in the condition to do >=, as suggested by Ted. Instead, you can simply put row < array.length. Also, null checks as per Ted's answer.

Comment: Actually, you need `!(row >= array.length)` since `array.length` is not a valid subscript for `array`.

Comment: Thanks Ted for pointing it out. Actually, to make it more clear, i would rather put the condition as row < array.length. Edited accordingly.